# Spring Rest Doc - url of the documentation generated

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I am using Spring Rest Doc, and I can see my .adoc files are generated properly in the path I have specified inside

```
public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation =
        new JUnitRestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");
```

now I would like to see it in action when I am starting the server.

my MockMvc look like this

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testController)
            .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
            .alwaysDo(document("{method-name}/{step}/"))
            .build();
```

I am trying to get the path for the documentation like localhost:8080/target/generated-snippet or localhost:8080/retrivedocumentation but I can't see it.
The documentation I found on line does not specify it. Does anyone knows how to retrive it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've followed the user guide instructions: [packaging the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration-packaging-the-documentation) then you'll find the docs along with the other static web resources:

`http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html`